# JavaScript reselect class personally in ListView

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating ListView using my template:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="ItemTemplate">
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:Info.shortName" class="shortName"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:value Converters.BeginValue" class="value"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:value Converters.EndValue" class="valueEnd"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:Info.longName"></div>
        <img data-win-bind="src:Info.flag" class="flag" />
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:change Converters.BeginChange" class="change"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:change Converters.EndValue" class="changeEnd"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:changePercent Converters.BeginChangePercent" class="changePercent"></div>
        <div data-win-bind="innerText:changePercent Converters.EndValue" class="changePercentEnd"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is when I meet the very long name I need to adjust font-size.

So I do (***for each element in list***):

**JavaScript:**

```
template = document.getElementById('ItemTemplate'); 
    // Adjust font - size 
    var name = item.data.Info.longName;
    // Split by words
    var parts = name.split(' ');
    // Count words
    var count = parts.filter(function(value) {
        return value !== undefined;
    }).length; 
    var longNameDiv = $(template).children("div").children("div").eq(4); 
    if (count > 2) {
        // Display very long names correctly
        $(longNameDiv).removeClass();
        $(longNameDiv).addClass("veryLongName");
    }

var rootDiv = document.createElement('div');
template.winControl.render(item.data, rootDiv);
return rootDiv;
```

**CSS:**

```
.veryLongName {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

But it doesn't effect selectivly. Moreover seems like it is check conditions for the first time and then just apply the same setting for remaining items. But it needs to change font-size to smaller only in case if the name is too long. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The solution is to work with rootDiv after it has been created. For some reason you can not modify each given template individually.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try by using following code instead, but u must include jquery for it.
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vH6G8/

Comment: @mahendra rajeshirke your demo not added `more_than10` class to first element which have text length greater then 10...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery's **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
$(".ItemTemplate > div").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text().length > 5);
}).addClass('more_than5');
$(".ItemTemplate > div").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text().length > 10);
}).removeClass('more_than5').addClass('more_than10');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xPXQC/3/)**

Comment: @user3722943 check updated answer its more efficient.